# R parallel took too many resources, how can I restrict the cores it uses?

Tags: r, machine-learning, parallel-processing, caret

I have used parallel in my training machine learning model process.

I used 5 cores to parallel.

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(5)
registerDoParallel(cl)

## All subsequent models are then run in parallel
# model <- train(y ~ ., data = training, method = "rf")
classifier2 = caret::train(x = train_x, 
                   y = y.factor,
                   method = 'xgbTree',
                   metric = "ROC", # if custom summary function is used, the specific metric correspond to it should be used.
                   tuneGrid = grid,
                   trControl = trainControl(method = "cv",
                                            number = 5,
                                            summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, 
                                            classProbs=T,
                                            savePredictions = T,
                                            verboseIter = TRUE))

## When you are done:
stopCluster(cl)
```

However, when I check the process using top in linuxs, I noticed 5 process is running and each took 7 cores to run, And the server totally has 40 cores. My jobs took 35 cores and that is almost 90%.

My teammates need the resource to run their jobs so I can't occupy most of them.

What should I do to use the parallel process and restrict each process/job only use like 2/3 cores in my work.

Comment: It would be useful to specify that `train()` comes from the `caret` package. Anyway xgbTree is using OpenMP for parallelization within a process which means that each process you make with `doParallel` will use more than 1 thread. Take a look at the Github issue here: https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/870 on how to limit the number of threads created.

Comment: @rps1227 Thanks!, sure I will take a look, hope I could find a solution~

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to rps1227's infomation

I found the answer here: [github.com/topepo/caret/issues/870](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/870)

The way to set max core for each running process is using nthread = max_num_you_want

So the final code is:

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(5)
registerDoParallel(cl)

## All subsequent models are then run in parallel
# model <- train(y ~ ., data = training, method = "rf")
classifier2 = caret::train(x = train_x, 
                   y = y.factor,
                   method = 'xgbTree',
                   metric = "ROC", # if custom summary function is used, the specific metric correspond to it should be used.
                   tuneGrid = grid,
                   nthread = 2,  # can be 3,4 if you wish
                   trControl = trainControl(method = "cv",
                                            number = 5,
                                            summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, 
                                            classProbs=T,
                                            savePredictions = T,
                                            verboseIter = TRUE))

## When you are done:
stopCluster(cl)
```

And that really restrict the process on my server only occupy two cpus at most.

By the way we can't use the argument allowParallel = F in trainControl, it will stop our training splitting to 5 subprocess but even with 1 process it took all the cpus to run, I think it is because caret::train itself will do some parallel process.